# Creating a custom section in a pytest report with specific instruction for failed tests in a certain module

Tags: python, testing, pytest, conftest

I'm already aware of the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874888/17643872) answer describing how to set-up a new section with a **general** message for all tests, but I would like to have a **special section** to **only** show up **if a test** from a **certain module fails**.

The story behind this is that I wrote a test for an analysis I conducted. I still want to develop the analysis functions further, but I'm quite confident that the results are correct. Therefore, I pickled all the results of my original version and wrote a test which compares the output under the current functions to the pickled original output (`test_stability.py`). To help my colleagues and myself, I now want to create a custom message which appears when a test in `test_stability.py` fails.

So, I have a file `test_stability.py` containing two tests:

```
#test_stability.py
import pytest

def test_form_stable():
      assert True
    
def test_content_stable():
      assert False
```

And another file containting two regular test `test_regular.py`:

```
#test_regular.py
import pytest

def test_first_reg():
      assert True
    
def test_second_reg():
      assert False
```

Ideally my pytest report would look like this:

```
collected 4 items

test_stability.py::test_form_stable PASSED
test_stability.py::test_content_stable FAILED
test_regular.py::test_first_reg PASSED
test_regular.py::test_second_reg Failed


============================================= FAILURES =============================================
____________________________________________ test_content_stability ____________________________________________

    def test_content_stability():
>        assert False
E        assert False

test_spam.py:9: AssertionError
____________________________________________ test_second_reg ____________________________________________

    def test_second_reg():
>        assert False
E        assert False

test_spam.py:9: AssertionError
---------------------------------------- My custom section -----------------------------------------
test_stability.py::test_content_stability says:   "My custom message"
================================ 2 failed, 2 passed in 0.07 seconds ================================
```