# Pytest plugin content in custom final section

Tags: plugins, pytest

I'm using the `pytest-rerunfailures` plugin to mark flaky tests in a large test suite. I like the addition the plugin makes to the output format as tests execute: I can see each test's status as it passes or fails, and if it fails, I can see the clearly-marked `RERUN` designation, followed by the next attempt at that test. This makes it easy to follow along as flaky tests fail and then get rerun.

[image: pytest console output as test is running]

However, `pytest-rerunfailures` does not show any `RERUN` information in the final "short test summary info" section of the terminal output (except for the final summary line, which doesn't show you which tests needed to be rerun) - it only shows Pass/Fail/Skipped/Xfail/Xpass/Error/Warning results (true even if pytest is run with the `-rA` command line option, wihch I did here):

[image]

I'd like to have the information from the first section available at the end of the test run so I don't have to scroll back pages and pages in the console to see which tests were rerun. I was looking at creating into a custom section at the end of the test run, based on the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874888/4402572). Using that tip, I'm able to print out a nice custom section (even in yellow, the same color the plugin marks RERUN outcomes). But I can't seem to figure out how to pull in the information I want: which tests were run when, and which of those required a rerun.

Can anyone lend a helping hand? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you specify the `-raR` option when you run, you do get a `final rerun info summary` section. It's black and white though, and doesn't "flow" as well as the initial `test session starts` section. It would be clearer to present the final rerun info section in the same way as the initial section is presented: color-coded, and delineating each test attempt in succession, not just a summary of which tests required a rerun.

[image]